# Packing of non rectangular objects

Tags: algorithm, sorting, polygon, packing

I would have set of objects in different shapes and size. Total count of those object would be under 20 or so. Each object can be defined in maybe max 30 polygon points. Processing time is not critical. The goal is to place those in the area with fixed width but unlimited length. There would be two modes, in mode A objects can be rotated freely but in mode B only 180 degree rotations are allowed (for example wood grain).

I'm aware this is NP-hard problem and a okayish solution is enough. Most of the articles are about rectangular objects packing but in this case it would be very wasteful as the objects usually have curves. What would be the way to tackle this?

Edit: It is given that all objects do fit in the area if length is not limited. However, the shorter the length the better.

Comment: You want to place arbitrary shapes in an `a x infinite` area and then what? Is the question how to place it so that the used area (length) is minimal? Is it guaranteed that all shapes can fit in the limited height somehow?

Comment: You could give a look at [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4308483&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4308483).